# Get all Post as per Category and Tag ( from url parameter) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters, customization

I want a custom page where i can get all post as per Url Parameter ( cat and tag )

```
<a href="localhost/celeb_page.php?cat=38&tag=aamir-khan" >View All Photo of Aamir</a>
```

Note : `cat=38` is my category which is `Photo gallery` and `tag = aamir-khan` is `taxonomy slug`

hence if some one click above link then the photo gallery post related to `aamir khan` will be seen as per its cat id and tag

note its not any custom post and nor custom taxonomy.

It bit confusing me in wrodpress

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help you to get posts form category and tag. You can get the category and tag from the url.

```
  $category=$_GET["category"];
  $tag=$_GET["tag"];
  global $wp_query;
            $args = array(
            'category__and' => $category, 
            'tag__in' => $tag, //must use tag id for this field
            'posts_per_page' => -1); //get all posts

   $posts = get_posts($args);
            foreach ($posts as $post) :
      //do stuff 
         endforeach;
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply but as said i want post as per my URL pass parameter category id and tag slug

Comment: i think you can get the category and tag from the url itself.

Comment: yes i got , it working now , actually i was not getting category and tag value from url ... as i have on permalink  hence it was causing the problem ..done .. it working now ..thanks for u r support till now